# I am not getting the proper output in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
exports.createBootcamp = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const bootcamp = Bootcamp.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: bootcamp
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
};
```

Please help me out. I am not getting the output data array. It only shows success as true, whereas I have given the 400 Bad Request. Name is the unique field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to wait for the bootcamp to be created before sending back the response. Just try putting `await` keyword as shown below:

`const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.create(req.body);`

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew Bui for your valuable response.